# How much video memory does Intel HD 5500 support?

Tags: memory, graphics-card, cpu

My question has two parts. First, I am having a hard time understanding how much video memory Intel's integrated graphics like Intel HD Graphics 5500 support. [Specs for Core i3-5005U](http://ark.intel.com/products/84695/Intel-Core-i3-5005U-Processor-3M-Cache-2_00-GHz) shows 16 GB for Graphics Video Max Memory. **Does this mean that this Intel HD 5500 can use up to 16 GB of memory?**
If so, then another question that strikes me is 16 GB is pretty huge memory. However, [NoteBook Check](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-HD-Graphics-5500.125586.0.html) says that this video card can run many popular 2014/2015 games will run fluently only at very low settings. What determines how powerful a video card is?

Comment: It looks like it is :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the GPU and CPU share the same RAM, the available GPU memory will be the amount of free memory reported by the OS.

I clicked the <kbd>?</kbd> button next to "Graphics Video Max Memory" on the link you posted.

> Graphics Video Max Memory
>
> The maximum amount of memory accessible to processor graphics.
>   Processor graphics operates on the same physical memory as the CPU
>   (subject to OS, driver, and other system limitations).

EDIT: (for your additional question)

> http://www.pcgamer.com/how-to-buy-a-graphics-card-six-things-you-must-know-about-gpus/
>
> **Memory: size doesn't matter, but bandwidth is critical**
>
> Selecting a graphics card because it has more memory is like choosing
>   an exotic car based on the size of the gas tank. The unwarranted
>   fixation on the amount of RAM is the biggest, most common mistake made
>   by gamers looking to buy graphics hardware.